# What's an example of a function $f \colon (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ with $f' \to 0$ and $\frac{1}{f}$ is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

What is an example of a function $f \colon (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ such that $f$ is differentiable, $f'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, and $\frac{1}{f}$ is integrable on $(0,\infty)$?

$\ln (x+1)$ doesn't work, and any polynomial term of $x$ doesn't work either.

Thank you.

EDIT

It's motivated by a question in Extreme Values, Regular Variation and Point Processes.

[image]

*Resnick, Sidney I.*, Extreme values, regular variation and point processes., Springer Series in Operations Research and Financial Engineering. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-0-387-75952-4). xiv+320 p. (2008). [ZBL1136.60004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1136.60004).

Comment: I don't believe there is any such function; do you have a reason for asking for an example?

Comment: @GregMartin It's from an exercise in a textbook I'm reading. I'll add a screenshot for added context

Comment: If $0$ is in the range of $f$, then $\infty$ would be in the range of $\frac{1}{f}$. So can $\frac{1}{f}$ even be integrable on $(0, \infty)$? Even if exact $0$ isn't in the range, it should be a limit point based on your definition for $f$

Comment: @TonyMathew - $f$ is specified as a function with codomain $(0,\infty)$, i.e. it has no roots.

Comment: @coiso: Or $f(x) = 1+x^2$ rather.  ($1/x^2$ fails to be integrable near $x=0$.)

Comment: @coiso but $f'(x) = 2x$, and that doesn't tend to $0$

Comment: @Phil I wasn't responding to your question, I was responding to Tony's comment. At any rate, I should have been more careful with my example. I believe $f(x)=\sqrt{x}+x^2$ is a diffeomorphism $(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ whose integral over all of $(0,\infty)$ exists.

Comment: I put in the full citation of the book I assume you are talking about.  Please double check and include full citations in future, not just titles.  There is a Cite button in the post editor that can pull citation info from Zbmath.

Comment: @coiso maybe, that would make more sense

Comment: @coiso: That would be redundant: if $f$ is differentiable then in particular it is continuous, and every continuous function has an antiderivative (fundamental theorem of calculus).

Comment: Ah, true. ${}{}$

Comment: In context, if we're wanting to show $H \in \Gamma$, then _we don't even want_ $1/f$ to be integrable on $(0,\infty)$ (if it were, we'd have an easy proof that $H \not\in \Gamma$).  Presumably the assumption is supposed to be $1/f$ is integrable on each $(0,x]$, so it's precisely the behavior of $1/f$ near $0$ that we're controlling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following argument shows there is no such function.

We are given that $\int_1^\infty 1/f(t)\,dt$ exists (choosing an arbitrary lower endpoint to avoid caring about the left end). But $f'(t)$ is bounded in absolute value on $[1,\infty)$ since it tends to $0$ as $t\to\infty$. (I guess I'm assuming that $f'$ is continuous.) Therefore by comparison, $\int_1^\infty f'(t)/f(t)\,dt$ also exists.

But on the other hand, $\int_1^\infty f'(t)/f(t)\,dt = \log f(t)|_1^\infty = \lim_{t\to\infty} \log f(t) - \log f(1)$, and therefore $\lim_{t\to\infty} \log f(t)$ must exist, whereby $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)$ also exists. In particular, $f(t)$ is bounded above on $[1,\infty)$, whereby $1/f(t)$ is bounded below by a positive constant on $[1,\infty)$, which implies that it is not integrable.